# Hitman falls in love, woman likely not target, maybe met in blind date

Tags: identify-this-movie

First post, hopfully I have enough info:

I believe I saw this moving on Neflix, but not sure.  Most likely the movie US-American, although possibly Canadian.  The main actors all had US-American accents at any rate.

I do not recall any actor's names.  The movie was a somewhat dark romantic comedy, or at least that's how I saw it.  Although there was a bit of action, the movie was definitely not an action movie.

It would have been relatively recent, possibly less than 10 years old.

The movie didn't have a particularly low-budget look or feel, but I would guess it wasn't a huge budget movie either.  Call it a low-ish budget.

I recall the actor was probably meant to be late twenties or early thirties, he was modestly tall, had dark hair (I think), and was pretty athletic.  I do not recall the actress.  I'm pretty sure the two main actors were not A-List actors.

Parts I remember:

- As I say, the woman in the movie is most likely not ever a target.
- Not too sure about this, but they might have met in a blind date.
- Through most of the movie, the woman does not know that the man is a hitman.
- There is one scene where the man is on the roof of a building fighting with a target, while simultaneously talking with the woman on his cell phone.  I'm pretty sure he had a blue-tooth ear piece.
- One scene, the woman complains about an annoying dog, so the hitman makes it "disappear".
- Another point, the woman complains about an annoying store manager (her boss maybe??), so the hitman makes him "disappear".
- I remember either the woman saying, or else one of her friends asking her, whether he "looks like Danny DeVito", or possibly using the term "so long as he doesn't look like Danny DeVito" (sorry Mr. DeVito if you're reading this...).
- I recall him taking bodies to be buried in the desert several times.  Based on how it looks, I would guess the desert scenes were filmed in California.
- In the end, she falls in love with him, even though she now knows he's a hitman.
- I'm pretty sure it ends with her helping him bury a body in the desert.  Possibly she's pregnant at that point?

Sorry, that's all I can recall.  Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The movie is called [Hit List](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1383705/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_11) from 2011

> Charlotte, Unlucky in love, ventures online to find a boyfriend. Just as she reaches her limit of unsuccessful dates, Charlotte meets her soul mate Lyle. Everything is perfect until Lyle finds Charlottes journal and sets out to prove just how deeply he loves her.

You can see the comment about looking like Danny DeVito, the ear piece scene and other parts that match your description in the trailer

Comment: YES - that's exactly the movie was thinking of!  Thank you!  I searched and searched and couldn't find it again.

Comment: glad I could help!